# How to create swipe for next/back UIImageView

Tags: ios, json, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have UIImageView like simple Gallery which get data from JSON.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *tmp =[allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"gallery"];
    if (tmp.count>0){

        for (NSDictionary *diction in tmp) {
            [self.patternImagesArray addObject:diction];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", self.patternImagesArray);
      //  [loading stopAnimating];

    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    PatternView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PatternCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *myPatternString = [[self.patternImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumb"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myPatternString]];
    cell.patternImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return cell;


}
```

For give full image i use this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    NSString *path=[_newsData valueForKey:@"bigimg"];

    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

        NSLog(@"%@", image);

    _imageParse.image = image;

    [_PanelTools setHidden:YES];


}
```

When i push on any image in my CollectionViewCell i can see full image, but how to create swipe left/right for next image or back. I know how to make swipe into the any side but how to create swipe with image next/back.

[image]

Comment: where do you show the full image? on a separate viewController, or on a view of the same viewController as the UICollectionView?

Comment: On a separate ViewController

Comment: OK, will update my answer within a few minutes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create two methods, -nextImage and -prevImage and put in the code for displaying the next and previous images respectively.

Then add swipe gesture recognizers using the following code in -viewDidLoad:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeImage:)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[_imageParse addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeImage:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[_imageParse addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

To be able to show the images, your need to first send the whole array of data instead of the dictionary with the current item. For this, convert the _newsData property to an NSArray and where you set the current item's dictionary in the new viewController, set the whole data instead. Also, introduce a new variable. Like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *newsData;
@property NSInteger currentIndex;
```

Introduce a method for showing the image based on index

```
-(void)showImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSString *path=[[_newsData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"bigimg"];
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

    NSLog(@"%@", image);

    _imageParse.image = image;
}
```

Now, in your viewDidLoad method, set the current image as:

```
[self showImageAtIndex:_currentIndex];
```

The -swipeImage method should look something like this:

```
-(void)swipeImage:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    NSInteger index = _currentIndex;

    if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        index++;
    }
    else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        index--;
    }

    if (index > 0 || index < ([_newsData count] - 1))
    {
        _currentIndex = index;
        [self showImageAtIndex:_currentIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Reached the end, swipe in opposite direction");
    }

}
```

Here's what your -prepareForSegue method of the GalleryControllerCollection class should look like:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    PatternView *cell = (PatternView *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    GalleryControllerFullmage *vc = (GalleryControllerFullmage*)segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.newsData = [_patternImagesArray copy];
    vc.currentIndex = indexPath.row;
}
```

Name the segue which transitions from the collection to the image view as "goToFullImage"

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToFullImage" sender:[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}
```

Comment: I know how to create Swipe, i don't know how to create next/back image which parse from JSON.

Comment: Your question seemed like you were asking so. Please rephrase it.

Comment: So please look on the image under the my question

Comment: I ll try in few minutes

Comment: I have three error: Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC also  Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to parameter of type 'id' and the last Local declaration of '_newsData' hides instance variable

Comment: Oops. my mistake with the newsData warning. Remove that line. Where are you getting the 'implicit conversion' warning?

Comment: -(void)showImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSString *path=[[_newsData objectForKey:index] valueForKey:@"bigimg"];
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];
    
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", image);
    
    _imageParse.image = image;
}

Comment: if (index < 0 || index > ([_newsData count] - 1))
 - Hide instance with _newsData...so i must delete this line or what?

Comment: NSString path=[[_newsData objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"bigimg"]; This is what I wrote in the answer

Comment: So when i open full image i have error - 2014-03-25 14:32:50.015 MissRussia[10808:70b] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a82da0
2014-03-25 14:32:50.034 MissRussia[10808:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a82da0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Did you change the data type of the _newsData to NSArray and pass  the complete array you got from the JSON to it?

Comment: I Am sorry i am lose my self...it's possible that i download my little project into the dropbox, and give direct link for you for check this mistake? Please.

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell]; - Unused variable indexPath. And so i must also to add swipe into the IB, it's true?

Comment: You also need to implement a -didSelect method in the collection view.

Comment: I added this code: - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _currentIndex = indexPath.row;
}
 but error still...

Comment: What i doing wrong? sorry for my stupid questions...but i create first gallery in my life.

Comment: It's all okey with my project?

Comment: Yeah, check the mail.

Answer (score 1):

Enable UIImage view user interaction which is disabled by default.

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Adding a Swipe Gesture Events

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
```

// Setting the swipe direction.

```
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
```

Handling Swipe Gesture Events

```
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {

        NSLog(@"Left Swipe");

    }

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {

        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");   

    } 

}
```